# How to open BIN file from Android app with custom extension?

Tags: android, mime-types, intentfilter

I am trying to open a file with `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` in Android Studio, and most formats I need open perfectly. However, BIN files are not 'caught' by my current filter, and I cannot figure out why. I am using the octet-stream mime type.

My intent-filter code is shown below.

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="file" />
                <data android:scheme="content" />

                <data android:mimeType="application/gzip" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/xml" />
</intent-filter>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is a bin file?

Comment: `FileRetrieval class`. What is that?

Comment: I changed FileRetrieval class to say Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. BIN refers to a binary file. –

Comment: Bin refers to gzip? Why didn't you give an example? All files are binary files.

Comment: I am referring to the file format. I am fairly certain .bin needs to be handled separately than .gz files in an intent filter.

Comment: What is in a .bin file? Which apps can handle it? You still did not come to the point.

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am also struggling that generic binary fails are not caught by the intent filter.